# Rails / Devise redirect after sign out

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wordpress, devise

I have a site that is split into an 'app' side and a wordpress side. The wordpress has static text that the client can update easily, hosted on Google. The app side is done in Rails, using Devise for auth, and hosted on Heroku.

I would like to redirect to the wordpress site after a user signs out, and am using after_sign_out_path_for to accomplish this. It works just fine locally, but on production I am getting aberrant behaviour.

The user clicks Sign Out, and the browser redirects to the wordpress site as expected.
However, the user is not actually logged out!
If they click on Sign In, they are directed straight onwards to the root_path without having to enter their credentials. Or if they navigate to eg https://www.theappsite.com/users/edit or https://www.theappsite.com/subscriptions/new (both of which have before_action :authenticate_user!), they can access them without entering their credentials.

Of note - I cannot duplicate this locally. It only happens in production. Locally, I get the redirect and the user must reauthenticate if they click Sign In.

My intuition is that the session or cookie is not getting destroyed before the redirect occurs, but I don't know why that would only occur in production... any advice would be appreciated!

**application_controller**

```
  def after_sign_out_path_for(resource_or_scope)
    # redirect to the wordpress site
    if Rails.env.production?
      'https://www.thewordpresssite.com'
    else
      #testing...
      'https://www.google.com'
    end
  end
```

**views/nav_bar.html.haml**

```
  %li.has-dropdown
    %a Account
    %ul.dropdown
      %li= link_to 'My Profile', edit_user_registration_path
      %li= link_to 'Subscriptions', accounts_path
      %li= link_to 'Payment Methods', payment_methods_path
      %li.fa-sign-in-alt= link_to 'Sign out', destroy_user_session_path, method: 'delete'
```

Answer (score 0):

HTTP is stateless, so it’s up to either the browser or your application to “remember” what needs to be remembered.

so you eed to end the user session by deleting it 
the session that is not the user and making sure the browser/server remembers the action in the cookies

you will find all  that you need and more in the link below

https://www.theodinproject.com/courses/ruby-on-rails/lessons/sessions-cookies-and-authentication